# Left join using HASH with missing values to be replaced with latest available value in SAS

Tags: sas, left-join, hashtable

I will have to join the following two tables.

**Table one (1 billion rows)**

```
input snapshotdate sourcekey sourcesystemid value1;
datalines;
20200101 112 5 788
20200102 112 5 789
20200103 112 5 800
20200201 112 5 786
20200202 112 5 777
20200203 112 5 834
20200301 112 5 789
20200302 112 5 771
20200303 112 5 832
20200101 222 6 788
20200102 222 6 789
20200103 222 6 800
20200201 222 6 786
20200202 222 6 777
20200203 222 6 834
20200301 222 6 789
20200302 222 6 771
20200303 222 6 832
;
run;
```

**Table Two (32 million rows)**

```
Data two;
input period sourcekey sourcesystemid npl;
datalines;
202001 112 5 999
202002 112 5 988
202001 222 6 555
202002 222 6 556
;
run;
```

I would like to get the joined table as below;

```
snapshotdate sourcekey sourcesystemid value1  NPL
20200101      112         5            788    999
20200102      112         5            789    999
20200103      112         5            800    999
20200201      112         5            786    988
20200202      112         5            777    988
20200203      112         5            834    988
20200301      112         5            789    988
20200302      112         5            771    988
20200303      112         5            832    988
20200101      222         6            788    555
20200102      222         6            789    555
20200103      222         6            800    555
20200201      222         6            786    556
20200202      222         6            777    556
20200203      222         6            834    556
20200301      222         6            789    556
20200302      222         6            771    556
20200303      222         6            832    556
```

When there is a missing (year and month), it has to be filled with the latest available value,
The code I have currently: (not working to replace the missing values).

```
Proc SQL;
Create Table want as
Select 
a.*,
b.npl
from one as a
left join two as b
on a.sourcekey =b.sourcekey and a.sourcesystemid = b.sourcesystemid and input(substr(put(a.snapshotdate,8.),1,6),6.) = b.period
order by a.sourcekey,a.snapshotdate
;
Quit;
```

Since it involves large tables, I prefer this to be coded using HASH. I would like to use table two  as HASH object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say a missing month and year, which table do you mean? Does the billion row table have missing values of years and months, or does the hash table need to add new values to the billion row table?

Comment: Are Period and Date SAS date values or numeric values as in the sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and you have sufficient memory, you can do this

```
data want(drop=period rc);
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(dataset : "two");
      h.definekey("sourcekey", "sourcesystemid", "period");
      h.definedata("npl");
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set one;
   if 0 then set two;

   rc = h.find(key : sourcekey, key : sourcesystemid, key : int(snapshotdate/100));
run;
```